# Grouping unique nodes with XSLT with condition

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping, nodes, transformation

I'm trying to do an XSL transformation to group up unique nodes in an XML file, which works fine, but doesn't take into account the condition on the Group.

Here is a sample XML input example :

```
<Rowsets>
<Rowset>
    <Row>

        <login>NG5E054</login>
        <Group>1</Group>
        <Competency>SKILL1</Competency>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <login>NG5E059</login>
        <Group>1</Group>
        <Competency>SKILL1</Competency>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <login>NG5E059</login>
        <Group>1</Group>
        <Competency>SKILL2</Competency>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <login>NG5E059</login>
        <Group>2</Group>
        <Competency>SKILL3</Competency>
    </Row>

</Rowset>
```

XSL Transformation that I'm using :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Row/login[not(.=preceding::*)]">
            <xsl:variable name="login" select="."/>
            <Row>
                <login><xsl:value-of select="$login"/></login>
                <Competency>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Row[login=$login]/Competency">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Competency>
            </Row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which returns :

```
<Rowsets>
<Rowset>
    <Row>
        <login>NG5E054</login>
        <Competency>SKILL1</Competency>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <login>NG5E059</login>
        <Competency>SKILL1, SKILL2, SKILL3</Competency>
    </Row>
</Rowset>
```

While my desired output is :

```
    <Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <login>NG5E054</login>
            <Group>1</Group>
            <Competency>SKILL1</Competency>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <login>NG5E059</login>
            <Group>1</Group>
            <Competency>SKILL1, SKILL2</Competency>
        </Row>
<Row>
            <login>NG5E059</login>
            <Group>2</Group>
            <Competency>SKILL3</Competency>
        </Row>

    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Thank you in advance !

Mehdi

Comment: The condition is on the Group node of course !

Comment: See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml for single level grouping and http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200101/msg00070.html for multi level grouping with XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Thank you Martin, Can you please elaborate on how to do multi level grouping without using Muenchian method ?

Comment: @MehdiMAHHOU, well I would use two nested `xsl:for-each-group` within XSLT 2.0 if asked to do nested grouping without Muenchian grouping. I don't see why you want to use XSLT 1.0 but don't want to use a well established approach like Muenchian grouping to solve it.